# AngularJS reset whole application

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on a hotel booking app using Ionic 1 and AngularJS.

When the room is booked you will be greeted by a ng-modal popup with your room Information and contact info etc etc.

I implemented a button that takes the user out of the modal window and back to the home page like this.

```
<a href="#tab/home" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <button class="button button-large button-balanced col" ng-click="modal.hide()" >
        <p style="color: white; font-size: 20px;">Thank you</p>
    </button>
```

I also want that same button to reset the whole application, is there an easy way to do this?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

When the modal window gets closed you are getting back to the parent controller, have a function implemented resetting the form and call the function.

```
$scope.reset = function(){

}
```

call it when you return back to the parent controller.

Comment: Cool, however, its a a very incomplete app as of right now, and I only have 1 controller and I am using states to travel between views.
Does your answer still hold strong or what do I have to do?

Comment: yes it should be valid even if you have single controller, try out and see

Comment: Thank you, you are very kind :) But I must be very stupid right now. What i did was
$scope.reset = function(){
        modal.hide();
        $scope.data = {}
        }
Data holds all information from the form.